# CakePHP without URL rewriting: redirect / to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, url-rewriting

I'm using a CakePHP framework on a shared hosting and cannot turn on `URL rewriting`.
The installation is in a folder called `/tc`. Everything works fine when I open `/tc/index.php/Controller/Action`.

However, I would like to make it a little easier for my users so that they do not have to open `/tc/index.php` but only /tc (which then should be redirected to `/tc/index.php`).

How do I do that with `.htaccess`?

Thank you!

**Clarificaiton**
I want a request on /tc/ to be redirected to /tc/index.php

### ***SOLUTION***

Worked for me with a simple

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

CakePHP handels the rest because all the links point to /tc/index.php/Controller.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: why do not you either contact them to turn it on or find a normal shared hosting ?

Comment: It actually works but I cannot use URL rewriting due to some problems when I call a controller over https from an external site. This only works, when URL rewriting is off =)

Answer (score 0):

Try Using following code in `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
   IndexIgnore *
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

1) open " mod_rewrite " from apache server.

2) comment " Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME')); " this line from /confige/core.php

Comment: it's a shared hosting and I have no access to do apache conf. And as I said, I cannot use URL rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the rule of **.htaccess** by which you can remove **index.php** from URL means if anyone enters http://example.com/index.php it redirects to http://example.com/.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9} /([^/]+/)*index.php HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index.php$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,NS,L]
```

Above are the two rules by which you can redirect index.php to root directory.

Comment: Thanks. But I want it the other way around:
If /tc is called, redirect to /tc/index.php